Тип предложения в данном случае

Твое будущее - в твоих руках.

Сказуемым будет "в руках" или пропущенное сказуемое "находится". Как это понять?


Твое будущее - в твоих руках.
Сказуемым будет "в руках" или пропущенное сказуемое "находится". Как это понять?

В этом предложении сказуемое отсутствует. Да оно и не требуется для раскрытия смысла этого предложения.
Предложение относится к т. наз. эллиптическим.

В таких предложениях отсутствует глагол-сказуемое, однако его смысл легко восстанавливается, причем для этого не требуется никакого контекста. Поэтому подобные предложения считаются семантически полными. Кроме того, в таких предложениях присутствуют «следы» сказуемого в виде приглагольных распространителей — дополнений и обстоятельств, что позволяет некоторым исследователям говорить о «нулевом сказуемом».
Кустова Г.И. «Синтаксис современного русского языка». М., 2013

А вот как подобные предложения описаны здесь — Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976:

Эллиптическое предложение.
Неполное по составу предложение, в котором отсутствие глагола-сказуемого является нормой. Для понимания такого предложения нет необходимости ни в контексте, ни в ситуации, так как полнота содержания достаточно выражена собственными лексико-грамматическими средствами данного предложения. На столе — стопочка книг и даже какой-то цветок в полубутылке из-под сливок (А. Н. Толстой). В углу старый кожаный диван (Симонов). Тёркин— дальше, автор — вслед (Твардовский). К барьеру! (Чехов), Счастливого плавания! С Новым годов!

Эллиптические предложения часто используются в лозунгах, призывах: Всё лучшее — детям.

Поняла, спасибо.
